# BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account App Crashed

Tags: android, google-account, network-connection

I am getting this error log when i started downloading something and moved on to **next activity** and then coming back to **previous activity** results in **App Crash**.  I searched for this [here](https://gist.github.com/mtrakal/6445a6ec5f6e98ea3bd1c1600862f7fa) as well but no solution is found. How this error occurs and What should I do to resolve this.

```
 [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:1513926394>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
                                            dgn: Long live credential not available.
                                                at dgo.a(:com.google.android.gms:3101)
                                                at dfc.a(:com.google.android.gms:399)
                                                at dfb.a(:com.google.android.gms:31371)
                                                at dfb.a(:com.google.android.gms:313)
                                                at egq.a(:com.google.android.gms:1201)
                                                at ego.a(:com.google.android.gms:3554)
                                                at ego.a(:com.google.android.gms:3196)
                                                at dbp.a(:com.google.android.gms:349)
                                                at dbp.a(:com.google.android.gms:213)
                                                at dby.a(:com.google.android.gms:1501)
                                                at dbx.a(:com.google.android.gms:914)
                                                at dbx.e(:com.google.android.gms:526)
                                                at dbx.d(:com.google.android.gms:445)
                                                at dbv.b(:com.google.android.gms:562)
                                                at jht.a(:com.google.android.gms:1080)
                                                at jgj.a(:com.google.android.gms:53)
                                                at bnz.a(:com.google.android.gms:5093)
                                                at bjv.run(:com.google.android.gms:65)
                                                at bjt.a(:com.google.android.gms:249)
                                                at bjt.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:242)
                                                at jly.run(:com.google.android.gms:139)
                                                at jmg.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                at jqr.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)



ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (WriteInterestRecordTask) got error response.
                                              com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online?
                                                  at bnz.a(:com.google.android.gms:5113)
                                                  at bjv.run(:com.google.android.gms:65)
                                                  at bjt.a(:com.google.android.gms:249)
                                                  at bjt.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:242)
                                                  at jly.run(:com.google.android.gms:139)
                                                  at jmg.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                  at jqr.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    10-05 13:43:15.101 3819-19797/? E/ctxmgr: [SyncServerInterestRecordsOperation]Failure response from WriteInterestRecord. StatusCode = -1
```

Need help, Thanks in advance !!

Comment: please provide some code where you are getting this error

Comment: Its a scenario @RahulKhurana.. I have list of data with buttons. If on click of one button I am downloading file then second button in next row is active which allows me to move on second activity. When I came back then app crashes. Being confidential I cannot put code here.

Comment: Sounds pretty easy to reproduce. Now provide the code, please, so someone can uncover the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been observed and is reported on [google samples github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/253). No reported solution to this issue.